# Does "when ~ dies, deal n damage to all players/creatures" have a name?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I saw [this tweet](https://twitter.com/RoboRosewater/status/790266290917240832) (of a neural network generated MTG card),  and tried to find a name for the ability "Simic Commander" has.

Using the gatherer I find [some](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=208003) [similar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382326) [cards](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=393979), but nothing with a name.

Does this kind of mechanic have a mechanical (preferably) or colloquial name?

Comment: Are you looking for a mechanical name of some sort, or a colloquial name like how we call [Just the Wind](http://magiccards.info/soi/en/71.html) a "bounce" effect?

Comment: @doppelgreener the mechanical name if possible,  otherwise a colloquial babe is fine.

Comment: Magma Phoenix is literally the only card ever printed with an ability that specifically matches the one you specify in your title. Are you looking for a name for that specific ability, or the trigger condition, or the effect?

Comment: Yeah, the other two cards just deal damage to *one* thing on death.

Comment: @murgatroid the name for that ability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Death triggers are common, but the EXACT ability that triggers is unique to Magma Phoenix. No other card dies and deals 3 damage to each creature and each player. In addition, no other card specifically just deals 3 damage to each creature and each player without some sort of additional restriction or specification.

If I had to shorthand it to a friend who I know is familiar with a long list of historical cards, I would just say that it dies and Bolts all creatures and players, in reference to Lightning Bolt.

Answer (score 4):

A [search](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[%22damage%20to%20each%20creature%20and%20each%20player%22]+[when]+[dies]) on Gatherer reveals that there are only two cards with exactly this ability. Based on that, I believe that it is very unlikely that it has a colloquial name. It definitely does not have a name used in the rules; if it did, that name would be used on cards instead.